# Form through ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to submit a simple form to a database using a little PHP script and it worked perfectly.

```
     div id="prontoform">
        <!--<p>*</p>-->
        <form action="procesar.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="input" value="" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre"></input>
            <input type="text" class="input" value="" name="mail" placeholder="mail"></input>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
```

but when i try to serialize it trough ajax is not working anymore, i get a new entry in my db but its empty and also the script returns me my own error message i dont know why

```
         jQuery(function($) { 
            $("#enviar").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    var opciones = {
                        method:"post",
                        url:"procesar.php",
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success:function(result){
                            $("body .exito").remove();
                            $("body .error").remove();
                            if(result=="exito"){
                                $("body").append("<div class='exito'>Sus datos fueron enviados correctamente.</div>");
                            }else{
                                $("body").append("<div class='error'>Error al enviar los datos, por favor intente denuevo.</div>");
                            }   
                        }   
                    };
                $.ajax(opciones);   
             });
         });
```

any clue on what's going on?

EDIT: this is the php script, as i said before it worked well without ajax.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    }else{
    $nombre = ""; 

  }

  if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    }else{
    $mail = ""; 

  }

    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'viveofer', '0Q51akeSf1');
    mysql_select_db("viveofer_1",$conn);
    $query ="INSERT INTO datos_pronto (nombre, mail)";
    $query .="VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$mail."')";       
    mysql_query($query) or die("Error sending data.<br>");   


 return "exito";

?>
```

Comment: Where's the code that inserts a new record into the db? Hard to tell without that.

Comment: If it's returning your own error message, what condition are you checking for that message?  When you debug this, are the same values POSTed to the server in both scenarios?  Is there an error in the PHP logs?  An error being returned from the database?

Comment: without ajax i get the values prompted in the form, when i use ajax i get an empty entry... the condition is when i "return:exito" in my php script

Comment: Warning: Your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection.  Users can pretty much run whatever code they want on your database.

Comment: Ok, so if it's actually storing empty data into a new row then that means your `$_POST` fields aren't being set when calling the script via AJAX. Check that your data is being processed correctly first before trying to insert into the db. You can `echo $nombre` to test.

Comment: David, what i should do to sanitize it?

Comment: Escape the user input.

Comment: can you explain further Jared?

Comment: Check this out: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('form', '#prontoform')` instead of `$('form')` in `data: $('form').serialize(),`..

There could be other forms in the page, by using `$('form')`, you might be targeting other forms.. By using `$('form', '#prontoform')` you'll be using form inside div `#prontoform`..

EDIT: As per the discussions the problem is with the line `method:"post",` it should be `type:"post",`

Comment: In that case from chrome console, network tab try to see what form data params are getting sent...

Comment: it is weird, my params are being sent to "procesar.php" but with the GET method, what does this means?

Comment: you got it!, im getting my params stored in the db, but the problem is that my error message is still being appended instead of the "exito" (success) message

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo "exito";` instead of `return "exito";`.. and see what is the return value on the same network tab

Comment: yes, i did notice that and i changed it, however still not working properly, even tough, looking at the network tab i get "exito" as a response from my script.. EDIT: the response is actually "exito" on line 1 and blank in a second line, why am i getting a second line?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

`$('#prontoform form').serialize();`

Instead of this

`$('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following demo code
Form id=frm

```
$("#frm").ajaxform(function(){

//here you can write your ajax before send,suceess and complete methods


}).submit();
```

You need to add jquery form

Comment: Yes, this requires a plugin for jQuery